# core.autocrlf true is not applied to a changed text file

Tags: git, eol

While having read a lot of documentation on EoL on different OS I am failing to understand why my yml file EoLs are not converted to LF automatically.
I made a mistake by creating a yml file in Notepad++ on Windows. However, I have core.autocrlf set to true. That's why I expect git to perform EoL convertion automatically. But no matter what I tried(editting the file again, replacing EoL in my IDE, etc.), I still see `^M` instead of proper line ending when I push my file into github.
For some reason setting a global property is not enough.

What helped me in the end is adding a .gitattributes file to a repo, as explained [here](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/).

So, despite the fact that I found a solution that I really like and, to my mind, is preferable because the configurations are stored along with the code, I want to understnad why `git config --global core.autocrlf true` didn't work for me when multiple sources state something akin to:

> core.autocrlf true: Git will process all text files and make sure that CRLF is replaced with LF when writing that file to the object database and turn all LF back into CRLF when writing out into the working directory.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Notepad++ supports "Text encoding formats including ASCII, Unicode, UTF-8 and several UTF-16 encodings". Several of these will result in Git believing that the file is *not* text (i.e., is binary) after which no CRLF-to-LF mapping will be done. Is that perhaps the issue?

Comment: Interesting point, @torek. I just think that git should be smarter than that. It has a heuristic algo, and I hope it takes a look at more than just encoding. And also the mappings inside .gitattribute suggest that git takes file extension into consideration.

Comment: Git does (use name patterns) *if* you put name patterns in your `.gitattributes`. It doesn't if you don't.